# Outlier Handing when most value is 0

Tags: data-cleaning, outlier

Just a question, i know that when we plot against the distribution of numerical data, those who fall outside of the boxplot (diamond shape point) are considered outlier. However, i met a case where majority of my data for that attributes is 0. The ratio is kinda messed up where its a comparison of roughly 5:3 where 5 is the ratio 0 while 3 is of the value other than 0 combined. Thus, the results it gives is q1 and q3 of 0. My question is , in this case, does value that falls outside of the IQR outlier calculation ((data<= upperlimit) & (data >= lowerlimit) works here or should i not consider doing this method?. The results of the data cleaning is the value of the attributes only consist of 0.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with boxplots and outliers, it's important to understand that the traditional method of identifying outliers using the IQR may not always be suitable, especially in cases where the data is heavily skewed or has a large number of zeros. The IQR is calculated as the difference between the third quartile (Q3) and the first quartile (Q1), and typically, any data point more than 1.5 times the IQR above Q3 or below Q1 is considered an outlier.

It's crucial to consider the context of your data:
If having a large number of zeros is common and expected due to the nature of the data, then these zeros should not be treated as outliers. You might want to consider using alternative methods for defining outliers in skewed distributions or when dealing with many identical values. For example, using the mean and standard deviation to identify outliers might be more appropriate in your case. If you know that certain non-zero values are valid and expected, they should not be automatically treated as outliers.

In some cases, transforming the data (e.g., using a log transformation) can help to normalize the distribution and make the IQR more meaningful. Additionally, a visual inspection of the data, possibly through a histogram or a different type of plot, might provide additional insights into the distribution and help identify outliers.

I hope this helps you in some way. Please provide more information on the nature of your data if you'd like a more detailed answer to your problem.

Comment: Well in my case, there are way too many 0 which make the non zero values seems to be an outlier. However, if i were trying to clear it, then my data will just be left with the one with 0 value, which i think will affect my data training. Should i try other approach or should i stop clearing the outliers.